# web application asp.net

Tags: c#

how do i connect two computers together using asp.net, similar to using TCP/IP where they connect through an ip-address and a port but im trying to avoid TCP/IP.  How can i do a similar way with  asp.net, http protocol

Comment: Even with ASP.NET (assuming web services), you're still going to be using TCP/IP.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you talking about using a web service?   asp.net/learn has tutorials for creating web services.

Comment: http relies on tcp/ip to transmit it's data.

Comment: Well im trying to connect to a server that would be open up at home and a webapplication where i can go on and connect to it over the internet and be able to send and receive data.  The data does not need to be save or anything, just to display at the other end.  im tryin to avoid non-http protocol because of firewalls.  Does the client side need to worry about firewall??

Comment: dnt u have to use a differnt port besides 80 for tcp/ip?? would that cause a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is really "can I create a web site" (to which the answer is obviously yes). And yes the appropriate firewall holes will need to be open; port 80 is indeed more *generally* open, but typically only servers expect *inbound* on 80 - so a little config may be necessary.

Comment: @user464111: +1 to your question because I find it intriguing. This question might be an ass-backwards way of asking something similar. I like your explanation in the comments having more detail about what you're trying to do.  Can you make those details part of the question by editing it further.  Also include how you envision it working (not from just a protocol perspective) but what you expect you as the user will do on the UI and what the result will be. I think you'll get some answers if you do that.  If it comes down to server issues you might try companion board http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

You... don't want to use IP?  That's going to be interesting in ASP .NET to say the least.  Are you sure you know what you mean?

Step back for a minute and give us an overview of your project and what you're trying to accomplish.  It sounds like you're unfamiliar with the terminology and technology being employed.  We can help with this, we just need to know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

@user464111 for what it's worth, what you're looking for is called "Client/Server application".

Good luck with that and feel free to ask if you'll have any specific questions while developing it.

If you want more answers start accepting those answers you already have on your various questions.